# SonarQube plugin development-c#

Tags: c#, plugins, sonarqube

I want to develop sonarqube plugin for c#. I developed some source code analysis tool in c# and I want to integrate into sonarqube. I just want to know  which IDE I must use for this work and how to setup project in that IDE . can I code this plugin in visual studio?

ThankYou

Comment: Why do you want to create a new C# plugin (see official [C# Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Plugin))? All plugins must be written in Java.

Comment: I developed some source code analysis tool in c# and I want to integrate into sonarqube.

Answer (score 1):

All plugins must be written in Java. You can execute your tool by Java code.

You should read [Developing Plugins](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Developing+Plugins) guide on the [SonarQube Wiki](http://docs.sonarqube.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Since the plugin must be written in Java you can't use Visual Studio. I would recommend IntelliJ and the plugin-project that I'm working on right now is Maven-type.
This is also a good guide on how to develop the plugin https://deors.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/sonarqube-plugins-1/